# Several "masters" in one git repo using Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm working on setting up a Azure DevOps with ONE project where i will plan work for several projects and i also want to save code for several projects under the same git repository.

Is the best practice to create several branches or can i create several "masters" somehow?

Comment: Why don't you want to use multiple repositories, one for each project?

Comment: Yeah one for each project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A branch more or less represents a state of the code on that branch. The master branch often represents a "latest version of code" state. If you really want to put it in one repository you are most likely better off just putting it all on the same branch and, depending on the projects needs, you should probably store the projects in separate directories.

You can also  create multiple repositories for the same Azure project on Azure devops

Comment: Oh did not see that i could create several repositories in one project. Thanks!